# Add query params to current child route from parent route component in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have a routing configuration like so:

```
[
  {
    path: 'parent',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'child-one',
        component: ChildOneComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'child-two',
        component: ChildTwoComponent
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Inside the `ParentComponent`, I have a button that, when clicked, should add a query parameter to the current route/URL. I've found other answers that suggest this solution:

```
// inside ParentComponent
constructor(
  private router: Router,
  private route: ActivatedRoute
) { }

onButtonClick() {
  this.router.navigate([], {
    relativeTo: this.route,
    queryParams: { myparam: true },
    queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
  })
}
```

However, using this solution in the `ParentComponent` causes the navigation to be relative to the parent route, not the child route. So, for example, if the user is at the URL `/parent/child-one` and clicks the button, the browser will navigate to `/parent?myparam=true` instead of `/parent/child-one?myparam=true`.

Since this code runs in the top component of my application, I'd rather not get into the messy business of traversing the `ActivatedRoute` object looking for the appropriate route to pass to the `relativeTo` parameter, since there are a lot of edge cases that could pop up.

The `Router` object does provide the full, current URL in its `url` property, however, using that URL like so won't trigger a navigation event:

```
onButtonClick() {
  this.router.navigate([this.router.url], {
    queryParams: { myparam: true },
    queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
  })
}
```

Attempting the same thing with `this.router.navigateByUrl` also does not trigger a navigation event:

```
onButtonClick() {
  this.router.navigateByUrl(this.router.url, {
    queryParams: { myparam: true },
    queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
  })
}
```

Adding `replaceUrl: true` to the [NavigationExtras](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras) object (the second parameter to [navigateByUrl](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigateByUrl)) also does not cause a navigation event.

Comment: You can try to  use `this.router.navigateByUrl` instead

Comment: Calling `this.router.navigateByUrl` with the current URL doesn't trigger a navigation event either.

Comment: Did you add  { replaceUrl: true } parameter?

Comment: Yes, I tried with and without the `replaceUrl` parameter.

Comment: for me this way is work `        this.router.navigate([], {
            queryParams: { myparam: true },
            relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
            fragment: this.activatedRoute.snapshot.fragment,
            queryParamsHandling:'merge',
        });` . And doesn't matter which component  call it

Comment: When I use `relativeTo: this.activatedRoute` in the parent component, the parameter is added, but I am re-routed from the child component to the parent component. When I get a moment, I'll link to a functional example.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after much experimentation, I've come up with this solution:

```
onButtonClick() {
  const urlTree = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url)
  urlTree.queryParams['myparam'] = 'true'
  this.router.navigateByUrl(urlTree)
}
```

While working on a simplified example, I wasn't able to reproduce the problem, so I've clearly hit an edge case in my project, that I haven't been able to track down fully.

After digging through the source code of [navigateByUrl](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigateByUrl), it appears that the current URL and the new URL are compared and if they are determined to be the same, the navigation event is skipped. However, it looks like the [NavigationExtras](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras) parameter isn't being considered in this comparison, which obviously matters if you're changing the query string parameters. The solution outlined above negates this flaw because the query parameters are integrated into the first parameter to `navigateByUrl`, which is the parameter used to determine if the new URL matches the old one. (See the source code [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e51ec671a57c0a96d1fdd9bd327114e894b874ea/packages/router/src/router.ts#L1075).)

Answer (score 1):

In 'app-routing.module.ts' file, add the following code:

```
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
        paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always'
      })],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :)